# Dayjs - date is different locally compared to running on a hosted server

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, dayjs

I'm formatting a string (in the style 'THU 04 JUL 2024') to a date string, and I'm then using that date in a query to a database.

This is the code:

```
const groupDate = "THU 04 JUL 2024"
const myDate = dayjs(groupDate, 'Do MMM YYYY').format() 
// local server output: 2024-07-04T00:00:00+01:00 (correct) 
// production server output: 2024-07-04T00:00:00+00:00 (incorrect)
```

I need it to use the London time zone, based on whether the date is BST or GMT (e.g, a date in July would be +1, a date in January would be +0).

I've tried using the **utc** and **timezone** plugins, but it converts the date to 11pm the day before, e.g.
`dayjs(myDate, 'Do MMM YYYY').utc().format() // 2024-07-03T23:00:00Z`

Any help here would be great, thank you

**EDIT**

Solved thanks to the help of @Spender in the comments for getting me on the right path. The issue is because "THU 04 JUL 2024" in London occurs at 2024-07-03T23:00:00Z when converted to UTC.

Below is the working code:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
const utc = require("dayjs/plugin/utc")
dayjs.extend(utc)
----
const groupDate = "THU 04 JUL 2024"
const myDate = dayjs(groupDate, 'Do MMM YYYY').format();

 
const _utcOffset = myDate.slice(-6); // gets the offset in time from utc

dayjs(myDate).utcOffset(_utcOffset).format() // formats it, ignoring the original offset
```

I probably haven't explained this well, but it works.

Comment: Your server is in a different time zone than your local machine.

Comment: You can apparently get a plugin for dayjs called "UTC" and use it to force a time zone for a particular date.

Comment: This is because the start of "THU 04 JUL 2024" in London occurs at `2024-07-03T23:00:00Z` when converted to UTC. Of course, your database also stores date/time in UTC, right? This is good because the date search will be responsive to the user's local time. Think about it another way... what should you search for if someone hits you from the other side of the world if you don't want your search dates to be out by half a day? A date on its own (with no time), won't cut it.

Comment: Hi @spender -Thank you. I've just seen you're right about the UTC time. I'm quite new to this, so it's fairly confusing why it's happening. This is for an internal application, only within the uk, so no issues with those in different parts of the world accessing this data.
It's failing trying to hit this in my database, as it's outside of the validFrom / to range : ``validFrom: '2024-07-04T00:00:00+01:00'``. I can see mongodb has the value stored as a string.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I've solved it now, you got me on the right path @spender - thank you!